# The iPhone app does not run in my old xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode4

i made project in Xcode 4.1 in lion OS and when i run the same project in snow leopard 10.6.5 xcode version 3.2.4 i get lot's of error. what's the problem? is it possible to do any changes in project when i run in xcode 3.2?

Answer (score -1):

In xcode 4, Select your project and look for Project format on the right hand side. Try setting it to xcode 3.2 compatible.

Comment: thanx for reply... It's look same contain all .n .m .xib files contain all required file.

Comment: @Hiren: The files are there all right, but there are other parameters in the pbxproj as well.

Comment: checking all the parameter but i found it same for both